# Automating variable exists macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm trying to finesse a macro I did to see if a variable is still present and to assign it a null value

```
%macro VarExist(ds, var);
    %local rc dsid result;
    %let dsid =%sysfunc(open(&ds));
    
    %if %sysfunc(varnum(&dsid,&var)) > 0 %then %do;
        %let result =1;
        %put NOTE: Var &var exists in &ds;
    %end;
    %else %do;
        %let result= 0;
        %put NOTE: Variable &var was dropped at SDTM level per CDISC Compliance.
             Null value will be assigned.;
    
        data AE2;
            set work.&ds;
            &VAR=.;
        RUN;
    %END;
    %let rc=%sysfunc(close(&dsid));
%MEND VarExist;
    
%VarExist(ae1,AESDTH);
```

Is there a way to automatically assign the variables actual character/numeric origin? `vtype` maybe or `vvalue`?. Also for the AE2, can I do something like `&ds.n` or even just automatically assign it within the original `&ds` dataset. I only did another dataset to reality test that it was working. Any thoughts? Links to relevant papers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be any need to test if the variable exists or not.

```
 data ae2;
   set ae1;
   length AESDTH 8;
 run;
```

Comment: for purposes of CDISC compliance and SDTM to ADaM mapping sometimes this is required

Comment: What is required exactly?  Just define the variables with LENGTH and/or ATTRIB statements before the SET.  If the variable is not in the source dataset then its values will be missing, there is no need for the assignment statement to set it to missing. If the variable has the wrong type in input dataset you will get an error, which is a good thing.